# How to check if a table has a row with a specific id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I check if a table contains a row with a specific id using jQuery?

Comment: Since all IDs should be unique you can just use $('#theID').length > 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just

```
if($('#rowID').length){

  }
```

should be sufficient..

**ID's** on a page are unique.. So this check should do..

Comment: Unless the ID could be relocated onto a different element type, or into a different table.

Answer (score 6):

```
if ($('table#uniqueID').find('#rowID').length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the table, it's easier and faster without jQuery.

```
var table = $('table')[0];
if (table.rows["theId"])
    alert("Has the row!");
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/wUKyk/

Comment: why not `document.getElementById('rowID').length`, and the question does say "using jQuery" !

Comment: @adeneo: First of all because `getElementById` doesn't return a collection ;-) but mostly because it doesn't verify that the ID is used on a table row in the targeted table. ...and OP can use jQuery to get the row if he wants.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#elementID").length) { ... }
```

ID's are unique, so just checking if the ID exists with `length` is enough

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasRowX = $table.find('#rowX').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the answer given by 'I Hate Lazy', this also works if the row in question has a 'name' attribute instead of an 'id'. I.e.:

```
var table = $('table')[0];
if (table.rows["theName"])
    alert("Has the row!");
```